# Model R code for an S3 class structured as a data frame with columns identified by attribute(s)

Tags: r, class, methods, package

I am venturing into the world of creating an R S3 class for the first time. My basic object is just going to be a data frame or tibble with certain columns identified by the user, so that my class-specific functions know how to find what they need. The constructor is also going to add a few columns computed from the others, and impose an ordering based on particular columns and parameter values.

I am guessing that there is canonical code for this, but I am not sure where to find it. My thought was just to have a series of attributes that each contain the column name(s) of the appropriate column(s), but it would be nice if I could supply the alternative of names or numbers. I don't need fancy name creation features because I am starting with data frames that should already have them, but I do need to be able to access each column in my object by either its actual name or its attribute name.

I am not at all confident that I have the basic idea of how to do this down properly.  For example, I am unsure if if there is any advantage to having each column name or group of names be its own attribute, as vs having one attribute object consisting of a list of named char vectors of column names. I am a little fuzzy on the structure R imposes on multiple attributes, actually. But I am hoping to make this a package, so I want to do it right.

Anyone have a similar class handy that they would recommend as a model? Or a pointer to an a well-implemented base class of similar structure would also do the job (if implemented exclusively in R code).

Here is my basic idea of how I am doing the constructor:

```
distr <- function(X, inc, comp, AdultEq="sqrt", ..., major=NULL, minor=NULL,  
                 wt){
  attr(as.tbl(X), "class")    <- "distr" 
  attr(X, "income")           <- inc
  attr(X, "incomeComponents") <- comp
  attr(X, "adultEquiv")       <- AdultEq
  attr(X, "majorGroup")       <- major
  attr(X, "minorGroup")       <- minor
  attr(X, "weight")           <- wt
#  etc. 
# adjust income and components for household composition
  X <- mutate(X, adjInc = X[, income] / if(is.function(adultEquiv)) {
                adultEquiv(...)} else {equivLst[[adultEquiv]](...)},
             adjIncComp <- X[, incomeComponents] / if(is.function(adultEquiv)) {
               adultEquiv(...)} else {equivLst[[adultEquiv]](...)})

  X <- arrange(X, c(majorGroup, adjInc))
  X <- group_by(majorGroup)
  X <- mutate(X, cdf <- cumsum(weight/sum(weight)) )
# etc.
  }
```

Then I will have methods for weighted sums and quantiles, conditional means, summary statistics, a print method, and so forth.

I tried to create a new tag for R's s3-classes, but I guess I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 1):

With what you're describing, you could consider creating a new S4 class. S4 is a stricter version of S3, but it makes sense with your data structure. So, instead of attributes, you could use slots. This means you can verify the object [and each column], but it also means you'd give up data frame properties for something that's more like a general list. You could then set the generics (show/print, plot, summary, etc) for that class. Hadley's book is okay on S4 classes. I also found the R manual to be very useful.

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html

Comment: Thanks Mike! I agree that this might make sense, but I think I want to start simpler. When Hadley describes the S4 system as sophisticated and says the ins and outs are beyond the scope of his book, I think maybe intimidation is the better part of valor for a first effort.